# ignore a Property Change in History?

Tags: python

I don't want blender to write in history when interacting with properties, how can we do that?

For ex:

[image]

```
class SCATTER_AddonPref(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__
    addon_prefs = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences

    scatter_sliders_display          : BoolProperty(name="",description="",default=False) 
    scatter_sliders_vgroup           : BoolProperty(name="",description="",default=False) 
    scatter_sliders_curv_is_open     : BoolProperty(name="",description="",default=False) 
    scatter_sliders_curv_adv_is_open : BoolProperty(name="",description="",default=False) 
    scatter_proxy_is_open            : BoolProperty(name="",description="",default=False)
```

```
layout.prop(addon_prefs,'scatter_camera_is_open',text="bla category",emboss=False,icon='BLENDER')
if addon_prefs.scatter_camera_is_open:
    layout.label(text="blablabla")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end up with an operator which does not send any update:

```
class SCATTER_OT_panel_toggle(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname      = "scatter.test"
    bl_label       = ""
    bl_description = ""

    pref: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    def execute(self, context):

        addon_prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
        
        evaluated = getattr(addon_prefs,self.pref,)
        setattr(addon_prefs,self.pref, not evaluated)

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

UI code example:

```
row.operator(SCATTER_OT_panel_toggle.bl_idname, text=na, emboss=False,icon=ixon).pref = "scatter_radar_is_open"
```